# Permutations of array in PHP

Tags: php, permutation

I am using the following code (https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/getting-all-permutations-array-php) to get all permutations of an array in PHP:

```
$list = array();
function recursive_permutations($items,$perms = array( ))
{
 static $list;
 if (empty($items)) {
  $list[] = join(',', $perms);
 } else {
  for ($i = count($items)-1;$i>=0;--$i) {
   $newitems = $items;
   $newperms = $perms;
   list($foo) = array_splice($newitems, $i, 1);
   array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
   recursive_permutations($newitems, $newperms);
  };
  return $list;
 };
}
// FIRST RUN
$perms = recursive_permutations(range(1,3));
echo '<pre>' . print_r($perms, true) . '</pre>';
// SECOND RUN
$perms = recursive_permutations(range(4,6));
echo '<pre>' . print_r($perms, true) . '</pre>';
```

It works fine if I execute the function once. However, if I need to repeat the process for a second array, the result is added to the first result.

How can I get it to clear the result after the first run?

Comment: Either a) clear the static on the non recursive call, b) don't use static, and merge the returned array from the forward iteration into the current known list. e.g. `$list = array_merge($list, recursive_permutations(...))` (not tested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function recursive_permutations($items, $perms = [])
{
    $list = [];

    if (empty($items)) {
        $list[] = join(',', $perms);
    } else {
        for ($i = count($items) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
            $newitems = $items;
            $newperms = $perms;
            list($foo) = array_splice($newitems, $i, 1);
            array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
            $list = array_merge($list, recursive_permutations($newitems, $newperms));
        };
    };

    return $list;
}

// FIRST RUN
$perms = recursive_permutations(range(1, 3));
echo '<pre>' . print_r($perms, true) . '</pre>';
// SECOND RUN
$perms2 = recursive_permutations(range(4, 6));
echo '<pre>' . print_r($perms2, true) . '</pre>';
```